# Dbcontext object transient in dotnet core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm creating an webapi application in dotnet core with entity framework. When I gone through documentation. I can use DI to inject the dbcontext object in dotnet core. But when I'm doing this the whole application using one dbcontext object.  How do I make the dbcontext as transient? If any example is there it will really help me.

Please find my existing code below.

> **This is the code I wrote in ConfigureService**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.XXXXContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]),ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        }
```

> **This is the code i wrote in DBcontext class**

```
 public partial class XXXXContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public XXXXContext(DbContextOptions<XXXXContext> options) :base(options)
        {
            logger.Debug("XXXXContext created");
        }
     }
```

If you see i have written already Transient in the AddDbContext method.So everytime if it create object. My constructor should call. But i'm getting call only once.

Comment: we need to see your code dude......

Comment: I have edited my post with source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve already done this using a separated statement.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.XXXXContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

    services.AddTransient<DataAccess.XXXXContext>();
}
```